# Getting Status 9 on onCharacteristicWrite

Tags: android, kotlin

I get a status = 9 on onCharacteristicWrite. But I don't find any info about this status in the Google BLE Doc. Can someone help me. I'm using the BM62 Bluetooth chip.

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abGFt.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question when looking for the same thing, and eventually worked out what was the problem. From what I gathered, there's a limit to the size of the value you can set on the characteristic to be sent. In my particular case, I divided the value in parts of 20 bytes and managed to send all of it to our hardware. Hope this can be usefull for anyone having the same problem.